# gdef with @ifnextchar

Tags: macros, errors, conditionals, latex-base

I am trying to create a command with two or three arguments, that creates a new command.

In my classfile I have:

```
\def\foobar#1#2{\gdef\foo{#1, #2, \@ifnextchar\bgroup{foo}{bar}}}
```

If I call `\foobar{X}{Y}`, `\foo` generates `X, Y, foo`, but if I call `\foobar{X}{Y}{Z}` I get `Missing \begin{document}.` instead of `X, Y, barZ`.

---

Without using gdef it works:

```
\def\baz#1#2{#1, #2, \@ifnextchar\bgroup{foo}{bar}}
```

Comment: The `Missing \begin{document}` is because you're using it in the preamble, and it looks like a command to typeset stuff. Move the call after `\begin{document}`. Then try `\def\foobar#1#2{\gdef\foo{#1, #2, \@ifnextchar\bgroup{foo}{bar}}\foo}\foobar{X}{Y}\par\foobar{X}{Y}{Z}` (don't forget `\makeatletter` before) to see if it is what you want.

Comment: I see that @Manuel’s answer still has only got one upvote, which is mine.  If you found that answer useful, consider upvoting it, as well as accepting it.

Comment: I already accepted it and upvoted it, but my reputation is not high enough for upvotes to be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\def\foobar#1#2{%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup
    {\gdef\foo{#1, #2, foo}}
    {\gdef\foo{#1, #2, bar}}%
}
```

You need to put `\@ifnextchar` in the correct position. Which still doesn't do what you want. This is an option `\foobar{x}{y}` defines `\foo` to be `x, y, bar`; and `\foobar{x}{y}{z}` defines `\foo` to be `x, y, z`.

```
\def\foobar#1#2{%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup
    {\foobaraux{#1}{#2}}
    {\foobaraux{#1}{#2}{bar}}%
}
\def\foobaraux#1#2#3{%
  \gdef\foo{#1, #2, #3}%
}
```

May be cleaner with xparse

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand \foobar { m m g }
 {%
  \IfValueTF {#3}
   {\gdef\foo{#1,#2,#3}}
   {\gdef\foo{#1,#2,bar}}%
 }
```

altough the classic syntax is with an optional argument `\foobar{x}{y}[optional]`.

Comment: If I understand correctly what the OP says in their question, it should be `\IfValueTF{#3}{\gdef\foo{#1,#2,bar#3}}{\gdef\foo{#1,#2,foo}}`.

Answer (score 1):

In the classfile you have:

```
\def\foobar#1#2{\gdef\foo{#1, #2, \@ifnextchar\bgroup{foo}{bar}}}
```

Why do you use `\def` instead of `\newcommand`?

Be that as it may. According to that definition `\foobar` will in any case process exactly two arguments in order to define the macro `\foo`. `\foobar` will just define but not call/use/carry out/expand the macro `\foo`.
Therefore usage of `\foobar` in any case will not lead to typesetting anything.

`\foobar{X}{Y}` globally defines the macro `\foo` to expand to:
`X, Y, \@ifnextchar\bgroup{foo}{bar}`.

If `{Z}` is appended behind that call to `\foobar{X}{Y}` (so that the input looks like
`\foobar{X}{Y}{Z}`), defining `\foo` takes place in the same way: `\foobar` still processes just two arguments, i.e., the arguments `{X}` and `{Y}`, for defining the `\foo`-macro while not attempting to typeset anything. Then processing the `\foobar`-macro is done. Then (La)TeX will in the input-stream find the token sequence `{Z}` which is not processed yet as it does not form one of `\foobar`'s arguments, and (La)TeX will attempt to typeset that token sequence. This typesetting-attempt in turn leads to an error message when it takes place within the document's preamble, before `\begin{document}`.

---

By the way:

Always care about the time when things get carried out.
E.g., there is a 'definition-time', and there is an 'expansion-time'.

With your attempt, the `\@ifnextchar`-forking does not take place at the time of defining the `\foo`-macro. It will take place each time when the `\foo`-macro is expanded/carried out.

Perhaps having the `\@ifnextchar`-forking carried out at the time of defining `\foo` is closer to what you want:

```
\newcommand\foobar[2]{%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup%
              {\foobarhelper{#1}{#2}{bar}}%
              {\foobarhelper{#1}{#2}{foo}{}}%
}%
\newcommand\foobarhelper[4]{\gdef\foo{#1, #2, #3#4}}
```

If in the preamble you have, e.g.,

```
\foobar{X}{Y}%
\begin{document}
```

, this yields:

```
\@ifnextchar\bgroup%
            {\foobarhelper{X}{Y}{bar}}%
            {\foobarhelper{X}{Y}{foo}{}}%
\begin{document}
```

The `\@ifnextchar`-check will find that the `\begin`-token's meaning does not equal the meaning of the token `\bgroup`, thus that check will deliver
`\foobarhelper{X}{Y}{foo}{}` while leaving the `\begin`-token and everything behind it in place:

```
\foobarhelper{X}{Y}{foo}{}%
\begin{document}
```

The sequence `\foobarhelper{X}{Y}{foo}{}` in turn yields -- `\foobarhelper`'s fourth argument is empty --
`\gdef\foo{X, Y, foo}`:

```
\gdef\foo{X, Y, foo}
\begin{document}
```

---

If in the preamble you have, e.g.,

```
\foobar{X}{Y}{Z}%
\begin{document}
```

, this yields:

```
\@ifnextchar\bgroup%
            {\foobarhelper{X}{Y}{bar}}%
            {\foobarhelper{X}{Y}{foo}{}}%
{Z}%
\begin{document}
```

The `\@ifnextchar`-check will find that the meaning of the opening brace from the sequence `{Z}` does equal the meaning of the token `\bgroup`, thus that check will deliver
`\foobarhelper{X}{Y}{bar}` while leaving that opening brace and everything behind it in place:

```
\foobarhelper{X}{Y}{bar}%
{Z}%
\begin{document}
```

The sequence `\foobarhelper{X}{Y}{bar}{Z}` in turn yields
`\gdef\foo{X, Y, barZ}`:

```
\gdef\foo{X, Y, barZ}
\begin{document}
```